# How do I delete a printer driver using Powershell without the Remove-PrinterDriver cmdlet

Tags: powershell, printing, powershell-2.0, citrix, xenapp

I have a Citrix XenApp 6.5 Windows 2008 R2 server farm that does not have access to the Remove-PrinterDriver cmdlet. I want one server in the farm to monitor printer drivers on the other servers and delete bad printer drivers if found. So far I have tried the following wmi call, but I did not see a delete method in the objects returned.

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName otherServer -Class win32_printerdriver | Where-Object name -like "*PCL 5,3*"
```

I have also tried the following invoke expression line to try to delete a printer driver, but the driver still appears when I query printer drivers. Any help toward a solution is appreciated.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName otherServer -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Expression "rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dn /q /n`"HP Universal Printing PCL 5,3,Windows x64`"" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second command has the wrong switches, but it should work in general. You used /dn where you should have used /dd. In general it looks like you're doing this the hard way by using `Invoke-Command`. You should be able to just do:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /c\\otherserver /m "HP Universal Printing PCL 5" /h "x64" /v 3
```

Here's the full usage description as shown by `printui.exe /?`:

```
Usage: rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry [options] [@commandfile]
   /a[file] binary file name
   /b[name] base printer name
   /c[name] unc machine name if the action is on a remote machine
   /dl delete local printer
   /dn delete network printer connection
   /dd delete printer driver
   /e display printing preferences
   /f[file] either inf file or output file
   /F[file] location of an INF file that the INF file specified with /f may depend on
   /ga add per machine printer connections (the connection will be propagated to the user upon logon)
   /ge enum per machine printer connections
   /gd delete per machine printer connections (the connection will be deleted upon user logon)
   /h[arch] driver architecture one of the following, x86, x64 or Itanium
   /ia install printer driver using inf file
   /id install printer driver using add printer driver wizard
   /if install printer using inf file
   /ii install printer using add printer wizard with an inf file
   /il install printer using add printer wizard
   /in add network printer connection
   /ip install printer using network printer installation wizard
   /j[provider] print provider name
   /k print test page to specified printer, cannot be combined with command when installing a printer
   /l[path] printer driver source path
   /m[model] printer driver model name
   /n[name] printer name
   /o display printer queue view
   /p display printer properties
   /q quiet mode, do not display error messages
   /r[port] port name
   /s display server properties
   /Ss Store printer settings into a file
   /Sr Restore printer settings from a file
   Store or restore printer settings option flags that must be placed at the end of command:
    2   PRINTER_INFO_2
    7   PRINTER_INFO_7
    c   Color Profile
    d   PrinterData
    s   Security descriptor
    g   Global DevMode
    m   Minimal settings
    u   User DevMode
    r   Resolve name conflicts
    f   Force name
    p   Resolve port
    i   Driver name conflict
   /u use the existing printer driver if it's already installed
   /t[#] zero based index page to start on
   /v[version] driver version one of the following, "Type 2 - Kernel Mode" or "Type 3 - User Mode"
   /w prompt the user for a driver if specified driver is not found in the inf
   /y set printer as the default
   /Xg get printer settings
   /Xs set printer settings
   /z do not auto share this printer
   /Y do not auto generate a printer name
   /K changes the meaning of /h to accept 2, 3, 4 for x86, x64, or Itanium (respectively), and /v to accept 3 for "Type 3 - User Mode"
   /Z share this printer, can only be used with the /if option
   /? help this message
   @[file] command line argument file
   /Mw[message] show a warning message before committing the command
   /Mq[message] show a confirmation message before committing the command
   /W[flags] specifies flags and switches for the wizards (for APW & APDW)
    r   make the wizards to be restart-able from the last page
   /G[flags] specifies global flags and switches
    w   suppress setup driver warnings UI (super quiet mode)
   /R force selected driver to replace exisiting driver

Examples:
   Run server properties: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /s /t1 /c\\machine
   Run printer properties: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /p /n\\machine\printer
   Run add printer wizard locally: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /il 
   Run add printer wizard on \\machine: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /il /c\\machine
   Run queue view: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /o /n\\machine\printer
   Run inf install: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "Test Printer" /f c:\infpath\infFile.inf /r "lpt1:" /m "Brother DCP-128C"
   Run inf install (with inf dependency). In the example, prnbr002.inf depends on ntprint.inf
rundll32 printui.dll, PrintUIEntry /ia /m "Brother DCP-128C" /K /h x64 /v 3 /f "c:\infpath\prnbr002.inf" /F "c:\infpath\ntprint.inf"
   Run add printer wizard using inf: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ii /f c:\infpath\infFile.inf
   Add printer using inbox printer driver: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "Test Printer" /r "lpt1:" /m "Brother DCP-128C"
   Add per machine printer connection (the connection will be propagated to the user upon logon): 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /c\\machine /n\\machine\printer /j"LanMan Print Services"
   Delete per machine printer connection (the connection will be deleted upon user logon): 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /gd /c\\machine /n\\machine\printer
   Enumerate per machine printer connections: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ge /c\\machine
   Add printer driver using inf: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /c\\machine /m "Brother DCP-128C" /h "x86" /v "Type 3 - User Mode" /f c:\infpath\infFile.inf
   Add printer driver using inf: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /K /c\\machine /m "Brother DCP-128C" /h "x86" /v 3
   Add inbox printer driver: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /c\\machine /m "Brother DCP-128C" /h "Intel" /v "Type 3 - Kernel Mode"
   Remove printer driver: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /c\\machine /m "Brother DCP-128C" /h "x86" /v "Type 3 - User Mode"
   Remove printer driver: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /K /c\\machine /m "Brother DCP-128C" /h "x86" /v 3
   Set printer as default: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n "printer"
   Set printer comment: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" comment "My Cool Printer"
   Get printer settings: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xg /n "printer"
   Get printer settings saving results in a file: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /f "results.txt" /Xg /n "printer"
   Set printer settings command usage:
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" ?
   Store all printer settings into a file: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "printer" /a "file.dat"
   Restore all printer settings from a file: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "printer" /a "file.dat"
   Store printer information on level 2 into a file : 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "printer" /a "file.dat" 2
   Restore  from a file printer security descriptor: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "printer" /a "file.dat" s
   Restore  from a file printer global devmode and printer data: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "printer" /a "file.dat" g d
   Restore  from a file minimum settings and resolve port name: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "printer" /a "file.dat" m p
   Enable Client Side Rendering for a printer: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" ClientSideRender enabled
   Disable Client Side Rendering for a printer: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" ClientSideRender disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the WMI is the way to go for deleting printers, but you can delete wmi objects with:

```
$obj = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName otherServer -Class win32_printerdriver | Where-Object name -like "*PCL 5,3*"

$obj |Remove-WmiObject
```